# Typescript ignore line when compiling to javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to use an enum on my typescript class, but I am also trying to test it using Jest.

my enum class looks like this:

```
enum Register {
    A = "A",
    X = "X",
    Y = "Y",
    PC = "PC",
    SP = "SP"
}
Object.freeze(Register);
module.exports = Register;
```

At the top of my CPU class I have this line:

`import { Register } from  "./register";`

If I do this application loads in the browser and works fine. However, my Jest tests say:

`Cannot read property 'A' of undefined`

If I remove the curly braces around Register like this:

```
// @ts-expect-error - ./register is not a module - but this allows Jest test
import Register from  "./register";
```

I get no errors (due to suppression) and I can run my tests fine with the enum, but in the browser, it says `ReferenceError: CPU is not defined`

---

At the moment I am commenting on the lines out when I am running the app and uncommenting to type.

I was wondering, are there any typescript comments (similar to `@ts-ignore`) that will prevent the line from compiling to the Javascript file? - I include the enum js file in the HTML so that its available to the class, just wondering if there is a more automated solution to this problem.

Comment: If you don't use this module in a test, mock it. `import { Register }` is incorrect because `module.exports =` translates to either default or `*` import depending on the setup, not to named one. Why would you use module.exports with TS at all?

Comment: Again, its just a Jest thing, if the `module.exports =` is not set jest fails. but when its enabled its fine, but throws none critical errors in the browser (this would be another line I would ideally like to not have compiled to javascript. I am guessing from your response that there are no commands that prevent a line or block getting compiled

Comment: No, there's no such command, this should be addressed in another way. How does it fail? What is the error?

Comment: If `module.exports = Register;` is not defined when testing in Jest, the usage of the enum returns undefined.

If `module.exports = Register;` is defined in Register and `import Register from  "./register";` defined at the top of CPU, then Jest tests run and pass, but typescript throws the error - `Register is not a module` in VS Code. In the browser, the console error `CPU is not defined` is shown so it's not reading past the error line.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible. In your code, `Register` is supposed to be named export. If you don't have ES6 export like `export { Register }`, that's a mistake that needs to be fixed in the first place. Don't use CommonJS module.exports with TS unless you're 100% sure it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Its a shame, there is no command, but it is what is. I appreciate your feedback on the matter.